# Video Streaming over HTTP in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, video-streaming, mediaelement, http-streaming

I am trying to work on getting Video Streaming over HTTP in a windows phone 8 application.

These are the issues that i am facing,

- Unable to stream video using the MediaElement.
- unable to Stream video using the player framework by microsoft.

Things to be noted here, i am not using the IIS oriented servers.

The above will well when i hard code the server details from my local machine or isolated storage. But this does not work through HTTP.

Does anyone have any idea on this ?

If this is not possible, is there a way where i can have HTML5 streaming the video and have that included in my application ?